# Hard drives attached to a PCI sata adapter not being detected

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, sata

i have a StarTech.com PEXSAT34RH 4 Port PCI Express 2.0 SATA III 6Gbps RAID Controller Card installed on my ubuntu server thats running 21:04 and any hard drive that is attached to this controller card does not appear on my server.

i executed `lspci -v` to see if ubuntu server detects the card and it does.

Here is the output on the part that it lists the pci card:

```
09:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9230 PCIe 2.0 x2 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s RAID Controller (rev 11) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9230 PCIe 2.0 x2 4-port SATA 6 Gb/s RAID Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51, IOMMU group 19
        I/O ports at e050 [size=8]
        I/O ports at e040 [size=4]
        I/O ports at e030 [size=8]
        I/O ports at e020 [size=4]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=32]
        Memory at fce10000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Expansion ROM at fce00000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [e0] SATA HBA v0.0
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci
```

Anything else i can try?

i tried changing sata cables, tried different hard drives(i have 7 to try) and none of them gets detected when connected to this pci card.

Comment: This is a RAID controller. Did you create arrays yet?

Comment: no not yet. cant it work without raid?

Comment: Did you enter the cards bios with ctrl+m at boot yet ? As far as it offering JBOD support. The original documentation doesnt mention it, but sites selling it do.

Comment: I tried hitting ctrl+m on the post screen but the bios for the card never showed up. i will try again

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

https://www.startech.com/en-us/cards-adapters/pexsat34rh

There is no hint pointing to the support of single disks.

`Supports hardware RAID 0, 1, and 1+0 modes configured through BIOS`

Furthermore the title of your question is misleading.
You call the device a `PCI SATA adapter`.

PCI is a legacy technology. Your device is a `PCI express adapter`.

The manufacturer calls his product
`4 Port PCI Express 2.0 SATA III 6Gbps RAID Controller Card with HyperDuo SSD Tiering`.

Comment: Ok thank you for your explanation. I bought the wrong card it seems as all i wanted to to is add more hard drives into my server with the option to raid in the future